# how to save a text file to hive using table of context as schema

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have many project reports in text format (word and pdf). These files contains data that I want to extract; Such as references, keywords, names mentioned .......

I want to process these files with Apache spark and save the result to hive,
use the power of dataframe (use the table of context as schema) is that possible?

May you share with me any ideas about how to process these files?

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by "table of context as schema" ?

Comment: Subtitles of the document  (like Introduction , Abstract,Bibliography,......)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you will need to parse the files using [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) and manually create custom schema s as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema).

Let me know if this helps. Cheers.